# Unable to connect to postgresql after migration to 16.04

Tags: server, postgresql

I just moved from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and I am facing several issues.

When trying to connect to `psql` (last version) via pgAdmin III, the connection doesn't work. I get the message

> Server doesn't listen. The server doesn't accept connections: the connection library reports could not connet to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

If you encounter this message, please check if...

Comment: check the output of `netstat -lnpt | grep 5432` to ensure the postgres is running and listening on tcp port 5432. if not try to start it by `service postgresql start` and observe the logs to find the problem.

Comment: Include any error you find in the log files here.

Answer (score 1):

As you have upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04, I can guess `postgresql` packages has also get upgraded.

If that is indeed the case, there might be new configuration files from the updated package. And during configuring stage, it might have changed the port because the older port was already occupied by older version of postgresql.

I experienced a similar problem recently. In my case, when I installed 9.5 over 9.4, it's configuration files then started using port `5433` instead of default `5432`. As a result, I couldn't make a connection.

The solution was removing 9.4 and changing the value of the `port` in `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf` file to `5432` Again and then restart the service.

Here is the answer I wrote on StackOverflow about the problem and it's solution. You might want to read answer especially if you're using Rails with postgresql - [Connection refused (PGError) (postgresql and rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904997/connection-refused-pgerror-postgresql-and-rails/38824023#38824023)

Comment: Use the setup with the new port for the new Postgresql to run whatever migration/tests you need to validate the new database, while the old installation continues to run on the old 5432 port.  When completely satisified with the new setup, you can switch the port over and delete the old system.